# Blazor UI got delayed when calling async await function

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, blazor, mudblazor

I am using Blazor (web app) with .NET 8 and a dropdown (with MudBlazor). When the user chooses an item from the dropdown, I call an await function to the backend. The problem is it got delayed a few seconds after the user clicked on the dropdown to display the item name on the dropdown. I tried to remove the await function and it worked normally. Does this relate to the threading of Blazor?
The code looks like this:

```
protected async Task OnValueChanged(Vessel selectedVessel)
{
    // Do something            
    var info = await GetMoreVesselInfo(selectedVessel.Id);
    // Display more info on the map
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `await` then `var info` becomes a `Task`, not the result, so how are you displaying `info` immediately?  You probably need to show your select,

Comment: I presume `GetMoreVesselInfo` does a call to the backend and then a call to the database?  If so, the problem isn't really in your code, it's the services it depends on.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I don't want to display info immediately. Of course, I know it takes time to get data from the back-end. I want to display the value/name of the selected item on the dropdown right after the user selects it because this dropdown or its data does not relate to the await function to get more info.

Comment: @Neil Yes to your first question. I don't get your opinion. The dropdown value/name as far as I understand, does not relate to the info I get from the back-end. Its value/name is already there. The dropdown just needs to display it when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `GetMoreVesselInfo` is executing synchronously and doesn't yield.  Are you using async methods to access the data source?

To test this, try adding a `Task.Delay` at the top of `OnValueChanged` to force a yield and let the initial render event run immediately.

```
protected async Task OnValueChanged(Vessel selectedVessel)
{
    // Set the value
    await Task.Delay(1);
    // Do something            
    var info = await GetMoreVesselInfo(selectedVessel.Id);
    // Display more info on the map
}
```

Here's my demo page which works either way.  I've added in locking while processing.

```cs
<MudSelect Disabled="_processing" @bind-Value:get="_country" @bind-Value:set="this.OnCountryChanged">
    @foreach(var country in _countries)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@country">@country</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    private List<string> _countries = new() { "UK", "France", "Spain" };
    private string _country = "UK";
    private bool _processing;

    private async Task OnCountryChanged(string value)
    {
        _processing = true;
        _country = value;

         //mock a sync call
         await Task.Delay(1);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

         //Mock an async call
        //await Task.Delay(3000);

        _processing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like somebody didn't like Delay(1).  But when `Do Something` stands for some actual code _before_ the GetInfo() call then the order of those 2 lines is important.

Comment: Basically a copy and paste typo by me.  I nearly put in a `Task.Yield` to trigger your standard response! :-)  It all really depends on where the value actually gets set.  That bit is missing.  You don't need it for a normal select,  but I checked out the `MudSelect` and sure enough you get the delay with a non yielding await.  Thanks for wiping out the silly downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
protected async Task OnValueChanged(Vessel selectedVessel)
{
    // Do something            
    Task.Run(async () => await UpdateVesselInfo(selectedVessel.Id));
}

private async Task UpdateVesselInfo(int id)
{
    var info = await GetMoreVesselInfo(id);
    // Display more info on the map
}
```

Basically, move the whole 'get data' and 'update display' into a task, and run that asynchronously instead.  You may run into threading issues, especially if the user changes the dropdown several times quickly (as you don't know which of the updates will complete last).

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't totally clear but I assume the combobox's 'look and feel' is not right.

You have the comment `// Do something`, if there is some meaningful code there then the results won't show until there is an await somewhere in `GetMoreVesselInfo()`.

There is a way that could make the UI more responsive:

```
protected async Task OnValueChanged(Vessel selectedVessel)
{
    // Do something            
    await Task.Delay(1);  // allow a UI update
    var info = await GetMoreVesselInfo(selectedVessel.Id);
    // Display more info on the map
}
```

Comment: Someone doesn't like any of our answers.  The OP?  Valid [but not necessarily right due to the lack of detail in the question] answers getting downgraded are a bit of a novelty.

Comment: Not the OP.   I wouldn't make too much of this, voting on SO is often very weird.

Comment: Agreed.  Checking the OP profile page is a good trick to know.  Alex - apologies.

Comment: @HenkHolterman //Do something is just update some variables. Thank you for the idea. I tried your Task.Delay but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Ok. I changed your tags, take note. I haven't used MudBlazor fopr a while, you may need some expertise from them. Try creating and posting a  [mre] .